# Using Hour and Minutes in Comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has date and hours and i am looking to get in my `output > >` all with a particular date and hour and minutes of that day.

A particular person on the table can have a `date_added` of `10/12/2016 9:38:04 PM`

I want to pull all who have a date added of `10/12/2016` after `9:25:00PM`. I have tried different things but nothing worked, see below

`s.date_added >= '2016-12-10 9:25:04 PM' 
 s.date_added >= '12/10/2016 09:00:00 AM' 
 convert(s.date_added) >= '10/12/2016 9:25:04 PM'.`

I am using sql. I just want a code that will give me all those on a table that have a specific date added on the date added column. I am not trying to  format, just get an output

Comment: The question is not entirely clear to me, and also are you using MySQL or Oracle?  Please tag only with the appropriate database (unless you really want answers for both, for some reason).

Comment: Please edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; and (3) a single database tag.

Comment: I am using sql. I just want a code that will give me all those on a table that have a specific date and hours added on the date added column. I am not trying to format, just get an output

Comment: Use ISO8601 format *YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.nnn[ Z ]* `SELECT * FROM s WHERE date_added >= '2016-12-10T21:25:04.000'`

Comment: What column type is `date_added`?

Comment: it is type DATE

Answer (score 0):

set date to variable datetime before

```
  declare @dateParam datetime
  set @dateParam ='2016-12-10 9:25:04 PM' 
  s.date_added >=  @dateParam
 s.date_added >=  @dateParam
```

example comparison with just hour

```
 if datepart(hh,  @dateParam) >= datepart(hh,  s.date_added)
 print 'True'
 else
 print 'False'
```